# What is a similar application in Ubuntu as "Draw" in Windows?

Tags: software-recommendation

I need to make a snapshot by printing the screen (PrtSc) then paste the figure into an application in Ubuntu that is like "Draw" in Windows. Can anybody please tell me which software (installed by default) can do this or which one I should install? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krita is a creative application for raster images. You can work with photos or scanned images or start with a blank slate. There are easy to use tools for drawing lines, ellipses and rectangles, and the freehand tool is supported by pluggable "drawing assistants" that help you draw shapes that still have a freehand feeling to them.

ScreenRuler will display a ruler on screen which allows you to measure the other objects that you have there. ScreenRuler has an *On Top* option that locks it in position on top of an image so that you can use it like a ruler to help you draw straight lines.

To install Krita and ScreenRuler in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install krita screenruler
```

Comment: Hi Karel, I found LibreOffice Draw, however, Ctrl+V does not paste the cached screenshot? How should I paste a screenshot after pressing PrtSc?

Comment: In Draw select *File* -> *Open*, browse to the screenshot and click the *Open* button. If you also want to draw on the screenshot I recommend Krita from the default Ubuntu repositories instead of LibreOffice Draw.

Comment: your answer resolved my problems completely. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

Drawing is a software similar to the old MS Paint. It is available in the default repositories in Ubuntu 20.04+.

[image]
Open a terminal, and enter the following command to install it.

```
sudo apt install drawing
```

Answer (score 0):

First part of the question is about capturing screenshot into the clipboard. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> for full desktop, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> for the current window and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to select part of the screen. More info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html#keyboard-shortcuts).

As for easy to use app, similar to Draw/MS Paint, you can install [Pinta](https://www.pinta-project.com), it's easy to use and yet powerful:

```
sudo apt install pinta
```